# `adduser [options] user group` fails ubuntu 11.04

Tags: linux, bash, user-accounts

I'm want to use `adduser` 
However it doesn't seem to work if I provide the second argument for the user's group

```
root@a:~# adduser rick staff
adduser: The user `rick' does not exist.
```

The group exists

```
root@a:~# addgroup staff
addgroup: The group `staff' already exists.
```

The man page says this should work...

```
adduser [options] user group
```

Any ideas?

I can do:

```
adduser --ingroup staff rick
```

So no massive issue, just seems strange.

Comment: Could you pastebin `man adduser`? Seems odd...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rob, re-read the error message from `adduser` command: `The user rick does not exist.`. Later you write about group `staff`, which does exist. But `adduser` failed because user `rick` does not exist yet.

Comment: you're right, my bad, it's not clear from the man page but what im trying to run requires an existing user, so using --ingroup is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to add an user and add this user to a group, you should:

```
adduser newuser
usermod -aG thegroup newuser
```

If thegroup isn't yet created, you should create it before the usermod:

```
groupadd thegroup
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I know how, im asking why the documented method of `adduser` does not work

Comment: @Rob perhaps you are lookin for --gid or --ingroup ?

Comment: As per my original question, --ingroup works fine, this is nothing to do with groups, I'm trying to raise that there's an issue with `adduser [options] user group`